# Biquotient of a Lie group by closed subgroups

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Suppose that $G$ is a Lie group (not necessarily compact) and $P$ and $H$ are two closed Lie subgroups. Does anyone happen to know of some good references that cover the double coset space/biquotient $P\backslash G/H$? I haven't had much luck finding information about this (and only a little bit in the case $G$ is compact).

For example, $G/H$ is obviously a smooth homogeneous space, but is $P \backslash G/H$ even a manifold in general?

Comment: To my knowledge, there are no textbooks which cover biquotients in detail, though some (e.g., felix oprea tanré book on rational homotopy theory) cover a bit about them.  That said, at least when $G$ is compact these were the focus of my thesis and some subsequent work.  I'd be happy to answer questions you have!  To start, a general double coset space does *not* need to be a manifold, nor even a manifold with boundary.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you! I sent you an email to the address linked in your profile. :)